# Email to Salesforce - link to all matching contacts?

Tags: email, documentation, emailtosalesforce

In the Email to Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_my_email_2_sfdc_guidelines.htm&type=5), it states: "If Email to Salesforce matches an email address to multiple lead or contact records in Salesforce, you can associate the email with all matching records, the oldest record, or the record with the most activity."

Where can I make this change? It's not in the Email to Salesforce section of Setup. Right now I think our selection is oldest record but I would like to change it to all matching records

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a **per user** setting. Users can go to My Settings, Email, My Email to Salesforce, and specify the desired setting under Email Associations.

[image: Email Association Settings]

Comment: thanks, looks like this is correct. Do you know if there's any way to make this change in the Lightning experience mode?

Comment: @James sure. It's in the same menu, you get to it by clicking on your avatar in upper-right corner, clicking on Settings, and following the same click path.